# How challenging did you find Real Analysis before the penny dropped?

Tags: soft-question, advice

I've been following 'Understanding Analysis by Stephen Abbot' and have been struggling with exercise questions even after an in depth read of the chapters. I have read numerous statements by authors that 'if you can't do the exercises, then you haven't grasped the material properly', but I feel like I have grasped the concepts. I've read many 'how to' books to finally understand higher level math and persevered with a 'never giving up' attitude, but most exercises really throw me off. Even those in the first chapter which are meant to be on basic preliminary material.

Is this just the nature of studying Real Analysis? I'll be starting Abstract Algebra soon and have been advised to purchase 'J.B Fraleighs introduction'. Do other higher maths  subjects cause the same anxieties as Real Analysis?

Comment: Could you give some specific examples of problems that you find difficult?

Comment: You need to read Rudin. It's the only respectable analysis text, in my honest view. Only by reading baby Rudin (the bible of undergraduate mathematics) will you truly begin to learn analysis.

Comment: I've not long started either, but I'd say there's often a difference between grasping concepts and doing exercises—namely that an exercise can often require some useful little trick which isn't mentioned in the material: some algebraic manoeuvre, say. (And the author isn't writing about algebra, so leaves that part to you.)

Comment: MathematicsStudent is right, Baby Rudin is a really good place to jump in.  Later, you meet Papa Rudin and Grandpa Rudin as well! ;)

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122: I'd agree with you, but for your second sentence, and your use of "only" in your third sentence.

Comment: Helping you might require a socratic dialogue. Or, at least, see you in action working on an exercise. This is difficult to arrange here. Many students have trouble grokking how to read definitions, and how to use those definitions. The definitions in real analysis always involve quantifiers, and dealing with those requires a working understanding of the logic (propositions and predicates) as well as large enough bag of technical tricks to carry out the required estimates. Abstract algebra is more of the same, but, at least early on, it may be that there is a bit less trickery.

Comment: (cont'd) Possibly because in abstract algebra the students don't first need to "unlearn the calculus way of working on exercises". Which brings me to my point: studying abstract algebra and real analysis SUPPORT each other in the sense that learning the basic logic of working with concepts and definitions is the same. On the algebra side you get to start from a clean slate. On the analysis side the game is more about formalizing the intuition (hopefully) developed while studying calculus. - translating "a mental picture" into epsilons.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 I'm curious, why do you have that opinion? What is wrong with for example Pugh's book? I think that book far outshines Rudin in the exercises, because some chapters have over 100 problems; so if you're stuck on one, you have plenty of opportunities to practice more and come back when you have a little more experience. Also for explanations, I think Tao's book is the best. I really like Rudin too, but I'm curious why you think it's the only real analysis text.

Comment: Also given what the OP said in the question, I would strongly advise against Rudin at this point. They can go to it later, but at this moment I think something like Abott's text is much better for the OP.

Comment: I agree with @JyrkiLahtonen. And in my experience, any student who has a complete grasp of basic first-order logic (together with a practical deductive system) will find it easy to breeze through introductory courses in almost all areas of mathematics. It does get harder when you come to number theory and higher algebra such as field theory, because they have much more structural content (ad-hoc and specific to that area), but logic is a huge stepping stone.

Comment: Abbot was my first analysis text. When I moved to Texas A&M for grsd school it wasn't enough prep for my analysis courses. It's a springboard, but you get to learn the tricks by doing them. It's best to consult multiple sources.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few bits of advice...

First, draw pictures. Specifically, draw graphs of real-valued functions, and see what various theorems are telling you about these pictures. Draw pictures to help you solve problems, too. Pictures don’t constitute a solution or a proof, but they can often guide you towards the right line of reasoning.

Second, play with lots of examples. Suppose you’re studying a theorem that has several hypotheses. Think of examples where the hypotheses are satisfied and where they are not. If one of the hypotheses is not satisfied, maybe the theorem is no longer true. Think of examples that illustrate this.

Third, don’t expect things to be easy. Mathematics texts (and many teachers) have a nasty habit of showing you only the pretty final results, without showing you all the false starts and roadblocks and mess that preceded them. You won’t be able to write textbook mathematics on your first try. The first few attempts will probably be convoluted and ugly. Once you have a solution that works, then you can tidy it up and make it look as pretty as the stuff in textbooks.

Comment: Yeah I am very sad about the topic you mention in your last paragraph. I've read Paul Zeitz's "The Art and Craft of Problem Solving" and over 2 pages, he went over how one might discover all the Pythegorean triples; I learned soo much about how to solve and think about Diophantine equations just from that one example. Then I went to my Number Theory book from school and I was disgusted at the half page proof which taught me nothing.

Comment: Yep. Looking at cakes gives you almost zero insight into how to bake one.

Comment: A better analogy, maybe ... looking at pretty flowers doesn’t tell you about all the digging and manure that’s needed to grow them.

Comment: Haha yes. It's no problem that it required digging and manure; but if you're going to teach someone to grow beautiful flowers I think it's much faster and more efficient if you show them a little how to dig and fertilize, rather than letting them figure it out on their own.

Comment: Regarding the cakes, I think it's even more basic than baking them. It's understanding how on earth you might come up with the idea of a cake in the first place, when you've never eaten one and are faced with a pile of unpromising ingredients and a mysterious contraption that nobody's told you is an oven. (It has instructions, but they're in a strange foreign language and you can only understand them if you already know how to use it.)

Answer (score 13):

I have two insights I have gleaned from my personal struggle with similar difficulties:

First, if you are having trouble with exercises, find easier exercises on which to cut your teeth.  There are *always* easier exercises.  The point is to jump in at a place where you feel comfortable working so you can grow your skills naturally.  You may have to switch books to do it, but it can be done.  Skill grows inevitably with practice, but I think  you have to practice with what you can do.  Sometimes baby steps are the wisest way to go.  Just my thoughts . . .

Second, in my experience as a student, teacher, and researcher, some people are just naturally better at some subjects than they are at others.  I have seen people who could breeze through graduate algebra courses struggle to barely pass analysis or differential equations, and *vice versa*; and I think putting time in on what you have a natural knack for may contribute to your success in subjects which you find intrinsically more difficult.

I hope these words are helpful.  You are not alone.

Comment: Just to add to your comment that "people are just naturally better at some subjects than they are at other" there is also the possibility that you might 'naturally' struggle with real analysis, but find topology 'naturally' accessible, which will then make real analysis intuitive. Sometimes pushing through with a bare understanding of the main results and then going back works.

Comment: @BernardW:  yes; I couldn't really grasp Lebesgue integration very well until I learned the essentials of functional analysis.  Go figure!

Comment: @BernardW What you just described is exactly what I went through, I couldn't understand analysis at all, then I learned some general topology and things started to make sense.

Answer (score 4):

I would say that the ability to do the exercises is an indication that you have (or are currently) **mastering** the concepts, but that simply grasping them is a much lower bar.

My personal advice is the following: find some classmates and take turns teaching each other the material. Literally. Go find a study room or somewhere you can stand in front of a board and teach each other what you learned in class. Reprove theorems. Re-examine examples. Re-state definitions (from memory if you can). There is no better way to learn than to teach.

If that doesn't help, then my next bit of advice is to practice 'till you puke. Another answer stated something about easier exercises to cut your teeth; this is an amazing bit of advice. But don't feel compelled to get back up to the hard problems fast! Keep practicing **everything**, because you never know when it will all click, and what will be the cause of said click.

Answer (score 2):

There is already really good advice here; just wanted to add some stuff which I think hasn't been mentioned yet.

When you read a theorem, avoid reading the proof right away and try for a few minutes to see if you can prove it youself. It's totally fine if you cannot prove it; the main point of this exercise is to help you understand what the theorem is really saying and to make it more memorable. If you want to do more, you can do stuff such as cover the proof with a blank paper and progressively reveal it, while trying to guess the next line or the rest of the proof.

Also, you may want to do this: 5 minutes after reading the proof, try to write it up youself (or at least a briefer summary of it); this can be surprisingly difficult. If you cannot do it, read the proof again and repeat.

Similar thing for the exercises; if you cannot solve an exercise, look at the solution and try to understand it. Once you feel that you understand it, try to write up the proof yourself; and if you cannnot, read again and repeat.